# Pillow image methods vs attributes, why?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

`im.getbands()` is a method, `im.mode` is a property (there are other examples), I think both could be an attribute. So why is this the case?

I understand that `Image.open()` does not decode the whole image and Pillow only does so when it is necessary, but it seems as relevant for bands as for mode. Understanding this could help me remember.

Comment: In Python it really doesn't matter too much because of descriptors (and properties). It's very easy to change was was an attribute into a method call — so the answer may simply be it's the way it is for historical reasons (that's the way the original author did it.